# Access all ajax UIComponents passed by execute attribute in backing bean?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

The following code is a simple form used with ajax component:

```
<h:form id="loginform">
    <h:inputText id="username">
        <f:ajax event="blur" execute="loginform:username loginform:loginbutton" ... />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:inputText id="password">
        <f:ajax event="blur" execute="loginform:password loginform:loginbutton" ... />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton id="loginbutton" value="login" action="#{indexBean.authentication()}" />
</h:form>
```

I understand that execute attribute is a space-separated List of IDs for components that should be included in the Ajax request.

I can access the source component at backing bean with `AjaxBehaviorEvent.getComponent()` method, but how to access the rest of components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's available by [`PartialViewContext#getExecuteIds()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html#getExecuteIds()).

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Collection<String> executeIds = context.getPartialViewContext().getExecuteIds();
// ...
```

You can then use [`UIViewRoot#findComponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent(java.lang.String)) to find component by client ID.

```
for (String executeId : executeIds) {
    UIComponent component = context.getViewRoot().findComponent(executeId);
    // ...
}
```